# I having trouble with EJB in netbeans

Tags: netbeans

The time I was practicing a java web project on netbeans, but with EJB error while in the process of running the scheme, but there is no solution on the fix, hope you had similar problems guide me fix on,

Here is an image of the error :

![E:\accpTrading\nbproject\build-impl.xml:307: The module has not been deployed.
See the server log for details.][1]

I tried reinstalling the software as well as JDK & SDK, but still did not fix, refer to various forums, these people are lost, today I'm posting on this forum because a friend recommended. hope you help me. for a week I could not work because of this error.

Thank you all!

Comment: Please upload your image on free image-hosting websites like `tinypic.com`---you don't have the permissions to upload image directly on this website because of 'your' restricted rights!

Comment: Also, ensure that in your Project--->`under Web Pages Folder,there exists a folder called META-INF`!

Comment: Also please post the message from the server log and make sure you use an application server which supports EJB like glassfish.